# ui.bootstrap.timepicker returns 2h less than it should

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use ui.bootstrap.timepicker for adding time intervals in my app.
This is where I select time, and on button INSERT&SAVE send data to api.
[image]

Problem is, here you can see selected time, but when send it to API, time is 2 hour less.
this is request payload

```
{from_time: "2017-03-29T11:37:05.541Z", to_time: "2017-03-29T12:42:05.549Z"}
from_time:"2017-03-29T11:37:05.541Z"
to_time:"2017-03-29T12:42:05.549Z"
```

This is my html

```
<form class="form" role="form" ng-submit="addRow(fromUrbanTime, toUrbanTime)">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h5><b>{{'FROM'| translate}} (h)</b></h5>
                                <div uib-timepicker ng-model="fromUrbanTime" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></div>
                                    <hr>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h5><b>{{'TO'| translate}} (h)</b></h5>
                                 <div uib-timepicker ng-model="toUrbanTime" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></div>
                                 <hr>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Insert & Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{fromUrbanTime | date:'shortTime' }}</pre>
                     <pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{toUrbanTime | date:'shortTime' }}</pre>
                </form>
```

and this is my ctrl

```
//time picker
$scope.mytime = new Date();

 $scope.hstep = 1;
 $scope.mstep = 5;


 $scope.ismeridian = false;


 $scope.clear = function() {
 $scope.mytime = null;
 };
//adding new time intervals
$scope.addRow = function(fromUrban, toUrban){
var config = {
             headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "POST"}
        };
        var data = {
                        "from_time": fromUrban,
                        "to_time": toUrban
                    };

        $http.post(serviceBase + 'aaaaa/' + $scope.urbanConfig.id + '/screen-intervals', data, config)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    Notification.success({message: $filter('translate')('URBAN_TIME_RANGE'), delay: 3000, positionY: 'bottom', positionX: 'right'});
                    //startTimer();
                    $scope.urbanTimeRange.push(data);
                    $scope.$watchCollection('urbanTimeRange', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
}, true);
                })
```

Comment: Can you see the request being made in your browser dev tools? I just want to make sure te issue is not in the front end.. but in the back end.. you should see the same values being sent from the browser as you have selected

Comment: in my post request payload, time is 2 hours less....

Answer (score 1):

You local timezone seems to be GMT+2. `Date` objects created in JavaScript are always in the local timezone. Your back-end, however, seems to work in UTC, which is GMT+0, thus the conversion on the backend. If that is the case, then when the backend sends the dates back to the client, including the timezone info, they should again be created in a local timezone, meaning +2 hours.

Example:

```
var now = new Date()
console.log(now.toString()); // "Wed Mar 29 2017 15:03:10 GMT+0200 (FLE Daylight Time)"
```

After sent to the server, and converted to ISO format, should be turning into:

```
"2017-03-29T13:03:10.000Z"
```

And then if that value is delivered to the client:

```
var now = new Date("2017-03-29T13:03:10.000Z");
console.log(now.toString()); // "Wed Mar 29 2017 15:03:10 GMT+0200 (FLE Daylight Time)"
```